# Angular nested property binding inside [innerHTML]

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm dynamically adding come content to page, let's consider following example:

```js
const dataArray = [
  {id: 1, innerHtml: `Some plain Txt`},
  {id: 2, innerHtml: `Some plain Txt`},
  {id: 3, innerHtml: `Some plain Txt`},
]
```

And inside component template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let e of dataArray">
 <p [innerHTML]="e.innerHtml"></p>
</div>
```

All works fine, until I need some nested property binding, like following:

```js
...
  {id: 2, innerHtml = `Some plain Txt with anchor: <a [href]="'most/plain/url/link'" >Link</a>`},
...
```

I'm passing values via security bypass pipe:

```js
@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class Safe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

    transform(style) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
    }
}
```

But always resulting with: empty `href` property of `a` tag when not using security bypass pipe or with non-interpolated, copy-pasted version of it (e.g. `<a [href]="'non/interpolated'"></a>`)

Comment: Hey Tomas, the contents of innerHtml are not parsed by angular. There are ways to dynamically parse html for bindings, but it’s pretty complicated and quite heavy (you’ll have to ship the compiler with your build).

Comment: Ok, that was an answer I was looking for. Unfortunately for me, this is really heavy lifting... Thanks @MikeOne

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` tag is native element, so don't pass values as property bindings. Instead of `[href]="'most/plain/url/link'"` just do `href='most/plain/url/link'`.

```js
innerHtml: `Some plain Txt with anchor: <a href='most/plain/url/link' >Link</a>`
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yx8hga?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Oh I guess I don't express myself quite clear. The idea is, that URL actually is a variable, not a plain string, so parsing it and providing a binding would be a really desired way. Anyway I did my research and it requires run-time component compilation so... well I'll just tell my management it's not possible :D

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use href as angular input attribute since Angular is not going to parse it.
Please use href directly like href=‘/url’